# base_model.summary() Crashes my notebook and VS Code - ResNet101

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to print model summary in tensorflow and I think the model is large and it's crashing my notebook. The model is ResNet101.
[image: This is the result when trying to print summary()]

The whole computer comes to a halt, memory usage goes up to 99% and VS Code crashes. I have 16 GB of ram, so I didn't think printing something large would actually eat all my ram. Also, because the kernel crashes, all the variables are lost like history = model.fit() which I need to fine-tune the model afterwards. Moreover, I need to print base_model summary in order to choose from which layer to fine-tune from.

Is there a way to print the summary in another way and save the entire notebook with the variables, so I can continue working? I have checkpoints for model weights, but I need to keep track of past epochs through history to resume training afterwards.

Comment: have you tried with a simple py script from the terminal instead a jupyter notebook?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia to print the summary?

Comment: Yes, maybe is just an issue with the jupyter server and a "simple" script may consume less memory... also, I'm not quite sure how summary manage residual connections...

Comment: As mentioned above, you can try to use Python files to get the terminal output content to determine whether it is the problem of vscode or the problem of jupyter extension.

Comment: By the way, if you use classic Jupiter outside vscode, will it report an error? At the same time, can you run only one cell at a time to ensure that at which cell vscode crashes.

Comment: I am using Jupyter through VS Code only, I might try the classic Notebook tho. The cell that cause the problem is the one where I am trying to print model summary, It consumes 99% of my available memory and it will either crash VS Code or it will gray everything out as seen in the photo. @MingJie-MSFT

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/11031#issuecomment-1204667479) in GitHub for you. You can update it there, because the problem cannot be reproduced in my jupyter.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Thank you my dude, updated it with my own info!

Comment: If you are using linux, this issue could be caused by inadequately set Swap memory